# SAPUI5 List refresh updating but not working properly

Tags: sapui5

I have a list with checkboxes that is sorted by ticked on top, not ticked at bottom.

I've got the sorter in place and it refreshes on tick, but whichever checkbox I have selected it stays in place, but the label actually moves.

**Before selecting 'Front Shop'**
[image: Before checkbox selected]

**After selecting 'Front Shop**
[image]

The list is refreshed automatically and the Front Shop item moves to the top (as the sorter is in place) but where I selected the checkbox in position 3, the tick stays there after the refresh.

**View**

```
<List id="listCategories" noDataText="{i18n>noCategories}" items="{path:'/CategorySet',parameters:{select:'CategoryDesc,CategoryId,Active'},sorter:[{path:'Active',descending:true},{path:'CategoryDesc',descending:false}]}" headerText="{i18n>active}" class="sapUiMediumMarginTop rightAlign">
                        <items>
                            <InputListItem label="{CategoryDesc}">
                                <!-- If there is an X in the Active field, set the state of the CheckBox to TRUE -->
                                <CheckBox selected="{= ${Active} ==='X' ? true : false }" select="onSwitch"/>
                            </InputListItem>
                        </items>
                    </List>
```

**Controller**

```
// Set CheckBox status, X for true, blank for false
    onSwitch: function(oEvent) {
        var oEntry = {};
        var bindingContext = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext();
        var path = bindingContext.getPath();
        var object = bindingContext.getModel().getProperty(path);
        oEntry.CategoryId = object.CategoryId;
        oEntry.CategoryDesc = object.CategoryDesc;
        if (oEvent.getParameter("selected") === true) {
            oEntry.Active = "X";
        } else {
            oEntry.Active = "";
        }
        var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
        oModel.create("/CategorySet", oEntry, {
            success: function() {
                if (oEntry.Active === "X") {
                    MessageToast.show("Category set as Active", { duration: 2000 });
                }
                if (oEntry.Active === "") {
                    MessageToast.show("Category set as Inactive", { duration: 2000 });
                }
            },
            error: function(oError) {}
        });


    },
```